# How to restart a program in terminal when the program exit with error?

Tags: java, bash, terminal, crash, restart

I write a script for starting a terminal that start some instance of a java application (one for tab), sometime java application crashes but terminal continue to work and I need to restart java application automatically.
I need to start in a terminal because must see some outputs.

```
until terminal --tab -e "java -jar app.jar param0" --tab -e "java -jar app.jar param1"; do
sleep1
done
```

whit this code I'll restart terminal...(if it crashed)
How can I restart java application?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

In a loop. Check with ps and grep the process still runs. If not start it again. Success

Comment: Thanks, can you make an exmple?

Answer (score 0):

If the terminal is still functioning, use

```
ps (Comment: add "| grep <search-word>" if you're looking for a specific process)
```

To check if the application is really dead. If it's not, try to kill the process with

```
ps aux (Comment: Will show the process ID you need for the next command)
kill -9 <Process ID> (This will destroy the process and lose all unsaved data)
```

Then, all you need is run the script again.